# How to say abstract "this"?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, pronoun

I know *dies* is generally used to say *this* when referring to a noun. But what about if I want to say something like "This is ridiculous!" or "This is my story". Is there a German equivalent of expressing *this*? Or is it just one of those things where you have to play around with the language to say what you mean?

Comment: Herzlichen Glückwunsch, das ist die 6000. Frage auf german.stackexchange.com! – Congratulations, this is the 6000th question at german.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common translation is indeed "Es ist/Das ist":

> This is awesome -> Das ist fantastisch
>
> This is my story -> Das ist meine Geschichte

or the somewhat more generalized version with "Es ist", referencing a given state/situation:

> This is ridiculous -> Es ist lächerlich
>
> This is awkward -> Es ist (mir) peinlich

However, you can sometimes leave out 'this', e.g. in your given example.
Facing something that results in a

> "This is ridiculous!"

will often be expressed with

> "Wie lächerlich!"

This can be seen as emphasis.

Comment: Ist nicht "Wie lächerlich!" - "How ridiculous!"?

Comment: @addy2012 Ja, aber die Information, dass dies im Deutschen ebenfalls so gemacht werden kann, halte ich in dem Kontext für wertvoll.

Answer (score 4):

You could say "Dies ist lächerlich" but that sounds very unnatural and ridiculous.

You can say "Das ist lächerlich" or "Das ist meine Geschichte". This sounds perfectly natural.